# Defining temporal extent of INSPIRE data when it changes every day?

Tags: metadata, inspire

I am trying to create INSPIRE compliant metadata for a view service.
I am struggling with temporal extent however. The data concerns projects which started being recorded back in 2010, however the data available to the service will only show data concerning projects who are executed in the last year or the next 6 months. Of course, this is updated each day, so my temporal extent is moving.

How can I record this in the metadata?

Comment: I assume that you don't want to regenerate the metadata on a daily basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously one way to do it would be to update the metadata on a daily basis, changing the time range accordingly, and updating the metadata date.

An alternate way would be to do something like:

```
<gmd:temporalElement>
    <gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
        <gmd:extent>
            <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="someid">
                <gml:description>
                The most recent data.  At least data for the last 6 months is provided, in some cases this period is extended to a year
                </gml:description>
                <gml:beginPosition indeterminatePosition="unknown">
                Up to one year previous of today's date
                </gml:beginPosition>
                <gml:endPosition indeterminatePosition="now"/>
            </gml:TimePeriod>
        </gmd:extent>
    </gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
</gmd:temporalElement>
```

XPath:

`/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:identificationInfo[1]/srv:SV_ServiceIdentification[1]/srv:extent[1]/gmd:EX_Extent[1]/gmd:temporalElement[1]`

That is schema valid and semantically correct.

You probably should also add more information about the date range in the service metadata abstract.

XPath:

`/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:identificationInfo[1]/srv:SV_ServiceIdentification[1]/gmd:abstract[1]/gco:CharacterString[1]`